# Trying to save image in Oracle database

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle

I'm trying to check whether image could be save on oracle db or not but stuck at one point and the error is "invalid table name" I tried to debug and find the error but not able to identify why the issue is occurring. the table which I created is Par_Image is very basic and simple, and in the dotnet side I have  have some doubt at below code

insertCommand.Parameters.Add("Picture",OracleType.Blob, 0).Value

Here OracleType.Blob is there. Is it should be OracleDBType.Blob, but OracleDbType is not available so I have used OracleType.Blob but issue is still available. Trying to find out the error but getting no idea how to proceed. Maybe issue will be in my code or approach? If any other way is there then please let me know.

Oracle DB

```
create table Par_Image
(
  PRODUCT_ID    NUMBER(10) not null,
  Picture       BLOB  not null 
)
```

.aspx

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:FileUpload runat="server" ID="flImage" />
            <hr />
            <asp:Button runat="server" ValidationGroup="Details" ID="btnSubmit" Text="Upload" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" />
        </div>
        <asp:Label ID="lblSuccess" runat="server" ForeColor="Green" />
    </form>
```

C# side

```
  private byte[] ConvertImageToByteArray(System.Drawing.Image imageToConvert,
                                           System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat formatOfImage)
        {
            byte[] Ret;
            try
            {
                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    imageToConvert.Save(ms, formatOfImage);
                    Ret = ms.ToArray();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception) { throw; }
            return Ret;
        }




    protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                           System.Drawing.Image imag = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(flImage.PostedFile.InputStream);
            System.Data.OracleClient.OracleConnection conn = null;
            try
            {
                try
                {
                    conn = new System.Data.OracleClient.OracleConnection(
                        ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conndbprodnew"].ConnectionString);
                    conn.Open();
                    System.Data.OracleClient.OracleCommand insertCommand =
                        new System.Data.OracleClient.OracleCommand(
                        "Insert into [Par_Image] (PRODUCT_ID, Picture) Values (1, :Picture)", conn);
                    insertCommand.Parameters.Add("Picture",OracleType.Blob, 0).Value =
                        ConvertImageToByteArray(imag, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                    int queryResult = insertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    if (queryResult == 1)
                        lblSuccess.Text = "msg record Created Successfully";
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    lblSuccess.Text = "Error: " + ex.Message;
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                if (conn != null)
                    conn.Close();
            }
        }
```

Comment: "invalid" table name is unlikely to be related to any specific field. It means the database engine can't find the table. Check you're pointing your app at the correct database, and whether you need to specify a particular schema.

Comment: @hari can you check that your connection string connects to the correct instance where you created the table?

Comment: "Insert into [Par_Image] " looks suspiscious. Shouldn't that be "Insert into Par_Image" ?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: @halfer i will take care of it further